# How to make a rounded-corner WKWebView on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, calayer, appkit, wkwebview

How to make a rounded-corner WKWebView on OS X?

Previously with NSWebView, we can do it through layer:

```
webView.wantsLayer = YES;
webView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
webView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

But on WKWebView it no longer works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

layers don't perform implicit masking of the detail underneath it. To get the corner to mask, you should add the following to the code:

```
webView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

From the documentation of `CALayer`:

> When the value of this property is `YES`, Core Animation creates an implicit clipping mask that matches the bounds of the layer and includes any corner radius effects.
>
> The default value of this property is `NO`.

I used the following simple, example code, and it displays the rounded corners:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    WKWebView *wv = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.containerView.bounds
                                       configuration:[[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init]];
    wv.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable;
    [self.containerView addSubview:wv];
    wv.wantsLayer = YES;
    wv.layer.cornerRadius = 50;
    wv.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    [wv loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]]];
}
```

Comment: Sorry I missed that line in the question. It works with NSWebView but not WKWebView.

Comment: I've added some code that I used to test it, and it works just fine on OSX Yosemite - displaying the (in the example huge) rounded corners. I don't understand where you're having an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the code! It turns out I made some mistake so I didn't notice the rounded corner.

Comment: But the web view still has white background on it. Can I make it transparent?

Comment: Are you talking about the content or the corner radii? The corner inherits what ever color is coming from below the view (so if it's a plain window, then it inherits background color of the window).

Comment: I tried to make the corner fully transaprent, so I set the window as transparent. But I end up get this: http://cl.ly/image/0r3M3d2S3w1j

Comment: To demonstrate that the corners are not transparent, I decreased the width of the web view. I used `[self.window setOpaque:NO]; [self.window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];` to get a transparent window.

Comment: When I just throw that into the `windowDidLoad` method, just before instantiating the WKWebView, I get transparent corners on the window - you must be doing something else - e.g. is there another view within the window that you're making use of?